# Question about running multiple animations in sequence with Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I've only been using Framer Motion since today, and I wanted to know if it was possible to run several animations on an image and repeat one in particular.
Basically, I would like to make an image move and then do a gravity effect on it.

Comment: You should be able to run several animations and repeat one, but I'm not fully sure what you're asking.

Comment: To try to keep it simple. When the image is where I want it to be, I want it to "gravitate". I just need to know how to run the animation after the image is in the right place.

Comment: Oh, so like do one animation to enter the page, then just repeat a second animation forever?

Comment: It's exactly that ! sorry for my english btw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Luckily there is a fairly simple way to run multiple animations in framer motion and repeat the last one.

### Updated Answer:

We can use the `useAnimate()` hook to orchestrate [complex animations](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/#manual-controls) in sequence.

First use the `useAnimate()` hook to get the `scope` and `animate` objects:

```
const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
```

Then we will connect a `<motion.div>` to the hook using the `scope` as a ref:

```
<motion.div
  ref={scope}
  ...
  />
```

Next we set up the animation sequence we want to follow. Notice that on the final `animate` call we have set the [option](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-function/#options) `repeat` to `Infinity` so it will repeat forever.

```
async function myAnimation() {
    await animate(scope.current, { rotate: -90 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scale: 1.5 });
    await animate(scope.current, { rotate: 0 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scale: 1 });
    animate(
      scope.current,
      {
        x: 100
      },
      {
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatType: "mirror",
        ease: "easeInOut",
        duration: 1
      }
    );
  }
```

The last step is to call `myAnimation()` when the page first loads to start the animation sequence:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    myAnimation();
  }, []);
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-sequence-of-animations-framer-motion-10-nucjtm?file=/src/App.js) to show all of these parts together, (including an example of multiple repeating animations).

[image: Edit framer-motion sequence of animations framer-motion@10]

---

### Old Answer (framer-motion version 6):

> With the `useAnimation()` hook we can set up [component animation
> controls](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#component-animation-controls)
> and then have the ability to do any animations we want in sequence.
>
> First make sure to create an `AnimationControls` object:
>
> `const animationControls = useAnimation();`
>
> Then we will set up our `<motion.div>` to use the `AnimationControls`
> object we made:
>
> ````
>       <motion.div
>         style={{
>           width: 150,
>           height: 150,
>           borderRadius: 30,
>           backgroundColor: "#fff",
>         }}
>         animate={animationControls} // This will let us control the animation using the animationControls object
>       /> ```
>
> Next we set up the animation sequence we want to follow. Notice that
> on the final `.start` call we have set `transition` to have a property
> of `repeat: Infinity` so it will repeat forever.
>
> ```   async function sequence() {
>     await animationControls.start({ rotate: -90 });
>     await animationControls.start({ scale: 1.5 });
>     await animationControls.start({ rotate: 0 });
>     await animationControls.start({ scale: 1 });
>     animationControls.start({
>       x: 100,
>       transition: {
>         ease: "easeInOut",
>         duration: 1,
>         repeat: Infinity,
>         repeatType: "reverse"
>       }
>     });   } ```
>
> The last step is simply to call `sequence()` when the page mounts
> which will start the animation:
>
>    
> ```   useEffect(() => {
>     sequence();   }, []); ```
>
> Here is a
> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-sequence-of-animations-1uobnf?file=/src/App.js)
> to show all of these parts together. [![Edit framer-motion sequence of
> animations](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-sequence-of-animations-1uobnf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
> ````

Comment: `await` seems to work, but it isn't documented and the return type of animate doesn't seem to match. Does it work by accident or is it intended?

Comment: @cglacet I'm pretty sure this is intended, and is documented. See framer.com/motion/animate-function/###then and framer.com/motion/use-animate/##exit-animations

Comment: Yes, there are example using this, but it seems so hidden that it feels accidental. But I checked and it is briefly stated in the animate function description: "Provide a function to run when the animation is finished. This allows the animation to be awaited.". Its strange that its a side note even though it is so fundamental. Not sure to get why it feels such like a hack ... The documentation is pretty good on example but not so clear on how the API is built. Anyway, I guess it hasn't changed in a year so maybe it's not a happy accident. Cheers.